# Query in fetching mysql records using query

Tags: mysql

i created a table as below

```
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_det
        ( order_id INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         Cust_name_1 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        P_desc_1 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Drawing_num_1 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Material_1 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Operation_1 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Quantity_1 INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
         date_1 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
          Cust_name_2 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         P_desc_2 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Drawing_num_2 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Material_2 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Operation_2 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
         Quantity_2 INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
         date_2 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Cust_name_3 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         P_desc_3 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Drawing_num_3 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Material_3 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Operation_3 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Quantity_3 INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
         date_3 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Cust_name_4 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         P_desc_4 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Drawing_num_4 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Material_4 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Operation_4 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Quantity_4 INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
         date_4 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Cust_name_5 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         P_desc_5 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Drawing_num_5 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        Material_5 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Operation_5 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
         Quantity_5 INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
         date_5 CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(order_id))
```

there are entries in the table.
when i give

```
            SELECT * FROM order_det;
```

It works properly results shown in image_1.[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Q4q.png)

However when i give

```
            SELECT P_desc_1 FROM order_det WHERE Cust_name_1='vw';
```

it returns nothing.shown in image 2.[image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdJdi.png)

i dont know where i am going wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: Your data has parenthesis. `('vw'.)` which is different from your query `vw`

Comment: i updated mysql table from python.do u have ay suggetsion on how i should make the query work?

Comment: The correct query looks like `SELECT P_desc_1 FROM order_det WHERE Cust_name_1='(''vw''.)';` However, the data in these fields looks strange, always with special characters, which makes it complicated.